# Access HttpConfiguration.DependencyResolver in validation attribute

Tags: dependency-injection, asp.net-web-api2, autofac, dependency-resolver

I have a web api application with Autofac. For the input insert models I need to use validation attributes for the properties that indicate related entities.

```
public class Comment
    {
        [Required]
        [ExistentBookValidationAttribute]
        public int BookId { get; set; }
    }
```

In `ExistentBookValidationAttribute` I need to access a business service to do the validation. Since Autofac doesn't inject properties to the validation attributes I decided to use the dependency resolver to get the service manually. But I don't want to use `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver`. I'd like to use `DependencyResolver` from web api `HttpConfiguration`. So is that possible? Is `HttpConfiguration.DependencyResolver` accessable in the validation attributes?

Comment: Show the validation attribute code in a [mcve]

Comment: I would recommend using https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation instead of implementing the validation as an attribute